# Gitlab CI artifacts crashes with 403

Tags: gitlab, http-status-code-403, gitlab-ci

When I make a gitlab ci with artifacts (Android-Project) the build itself runs without problems. Also the Archiving is no problem, but when it comes to "Uploading artifacts" the ci gets a 403 - Forbidden. Anyone any idea?

Here are the last log entries:

```
Archiving cache...
INFO[0000] Creating archive cache.tgz ...               
INFO[0000] Done!                                        
Archiving artifacts...
INFO[0000] Creating archive artifacts.tgz ...           
INFO[0000] Done!                                        
Uploading artifacts...
8,7M    artifacts.tgz
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden

ERROR: Build failed with: exit status 1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was an internal problem in gitlab. The main problem got fixed after fixing all directory rights in the gitlab folder so apache could get write access on the necessary folders.

Comment: you would help others by sharing which folder(s) that would be.

Comment: For me, [this nginx link](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/nginx/gitlab-omnibus-ssl-nginx.conf) helped. For others the [apache link](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/apache) might do the trick.